# React Update Price with useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Im new on react and need help to implement a price counter with UseState.
What i want to do instead of the code bellow is to Use price as a useState instead like "const [price, setPrice] = useState(995)"

Depends how many employees there is the price will raise with 220.

Could someone help me?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Slider from 'rc-slider';
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState(1)
  
  let price = 0;
  
  const calculatePrice = () => {
    
    if (employees <= 4 && price !== 995) {

      return price = 995;
 

    } else if (employees >= 5 && employees <= 50) {

      return price = employees * 220;
     

    } else if (employees >= 51 && employees <= 100) {
      
      return price = 995 + employees * 200;
   

    } else if (employees >= 101 && employees <= 200) {
      
      return price = 995 + employees * 195;
    

    } else if (employees >= 201) {

      return price = "Kontakta oss för offert!";
     

    }

    return 345;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="calculator">

        <div>Pris: {calculatePrice()}</div>
        <div> Antal anställda: {employees}</div>
        {/* <div> anställd{employees !== 1 && 'a'} {employees}</div> */}
        <Slider
          min={1}
          max={201}
          value={employees}
          onChange={(v) => setEmployees(v)}
        />

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `price` appears to be a derived value from your `employees` state value. You don't generally store values in state that are easily derivable from state.

Comment: what is the problem with your code now ? it seems to be working, why do you need a `useState` to store the price ?

Comment: I think its much cleaner with it. And i also want to learn how to do it :)

Comment: it's not much cleaner, if price is related to the employee, it's perfectly valid to compute the price in your component, I think it's better thant using a state variable because the price will never be set by the user manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`price` appears to be a derived value from your `employees` state value. You don't generally store values in state that are easily derivable from state.

You can create a `price` state, but doing so would/could be considered an anti-pattern React.

[Identify the Minimal (but complete) Representation of UI State](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state)

> Let’s go through each one and figure out which one is state. Ask three
> questions about each piece of data:
>
> 1. Is it passed in from a parent via props? If so, it probably isn’t state.
> 2. Does it remain unchanged over time? If so, it probably isn’t state.
> 3. ***Can you compute it based on any other state or props in your component? If so, it isn’t state***.

## Not Recommended, but...

If you really wanted to, and you just want to see it and learn, then this is one way you could move the logic into `price` state. Use an `useEffect` hook to respond to updates on the `employees` state to recompute the `price state

```
function MyApp() {
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState(1);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(995);

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculatePrice = () => {
      if (employees <= 4) {
        return 995;
      } else if (employees <= 50) {
        return employees * 220;
      } else if (employees <= 100) {
        return 995 + employees * 200;
      } else if (employees <= 200) {
        return 995 + employees * 195;
      }
      return "Kontakta oss för offert!";
    };
    setPrice(calculatePrice());
  }, [employees]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="calculator">
        <div>Pris: {price}</div>
        <div> Antal anställda: {employees}</div>
        {/* <div> anställd{employees !== 1 && 'a'} {employees}</div> */}
        <Slider
          min={1}
          max={201}
          value={employees}
          onChange={(v) => setEmployees(v)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-update-price-with-usestate]

The more correct and optimal solution is the one you have already, computing the derived `price` value *from* your state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The answer was exactly what i wanted. I will try to read more about the Representation Ui state.